# Update if record exit ,insert/save if record not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a edit form which edit an array like (Invoice) , I want when i edit the Invoice_no a can also able to add the new item on the same invoice number

Example the `Inv_no=300` and its carry 3 arrays ([... .... ... ]), so I want to add the new one array to be 4 arrays.

On my code below is update array well data but if i add new one row does not save that new one while it keep update,

what can i do here to add/save the new one data.

```
public function update(Request $request, $inv_no)
 {
  $data = $request->all();
//dd($data);

   $stocks = Stock::where('inv_no', $inv_no)->get();
  $i = 0;

foreach ($stocks as $stock) {  
    Stock::where('inv_no', $inv_no)
        ->where('id', $stock->id)
        ->update([
            'pid' => $request->pid[$i],
            'qty' => $request->qty[$i],
            'inv_no' => $request->inv_no,
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'Indate'=>$request->Indate,
            'supplierName' => $request->supplierName,
            'receiptNumber' => $request->receiptNumber,
            'truckNumber' => $request->truckNumber,
            'driverName' => $request->driverName,
            'remark' => $request->remark,
        ]);

        $i++;
    }

   return $this->index();
  }
```

Comment: have you tried `updateOrCreate()`?

Comment: am tried but not works as need @djunehor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like that. You have mentioned that you need to update if the invoice number exists and you also want to a new item with this invoice number. If you have any query, feel free to ask me

```
public function update(Request $request, $inv_no)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $stocks = Stock::where('inv_no', $inv_no)->get();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($stocks as $stock) {
        $stock->update([
            'pid' => $request->pid[$i],
            'qty' => $request->qty[$i],
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'Indate'=>$request->Indate,
            'supplierName' => $request->supplierName,
            'receiptNumber' => $request->receiptNumber,
            'truckNumber' => $request->truckNumber,
            'driverName' => $request->driverName,
            'remark' => $request->remark,
        ]);
        $i++;
    }

    $totalPid = count($request->pid);
    $totalQty= count($request->qty);
    Stock::create([
        'pid' => $request->pid[$totalPid - 1],
        'qty' => $request->qty[$totalQty - 1],
        'inv_no' => $request->inv_no,
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'Indate'=>$request->Indate,
        'supplierName' => $request->supplierName,
        'receiptNumber' => $request->receiptNumber,
        'truckNumber' => $request->truckNumber,
        'driverName' => $request->driverName,
        'remark' => $request->remark,
    ]);

    return $this->index();
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU  BROTHER, Its works perfect update and add new items

Comment: ok, but one qns, why am get `Undefined offset: 3` when I update again, and it point `Stock::create([
        'pid' => $request->pid[$i],`

Comment: When you are updating again, you are not updating your request. Please show me your requested pid and qty

Comment: Maybe you are sending array but don't know why. Please explain it to me

Comment: Will be your $request->pid and $request->qty separate for each entry? Share your request with me, otherwise, how I help you?

Comment: https://zoom.us/j/93608946946?pwd=L0dmaENPLzhWZTRpd1oxRU1hMlE1Zz09

Meeting ID: 936 0894 6946
Password: 3QhR7r

Comment: Kindly just join the meeting then i can show you well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214123/discussion-between-mukti-rani-ghosh-and-emma-mfinanga).

Comment: Am tried to add many row there it just add one pls can we recheck again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `updateOrCreate` method:

```php
foreach ($stocks as $stock) {  
    Stock::updateOrCreate(['id' => $stock->id], [
       'pid' => $request->pid[$i],
       'qty' => $request->qty[$i],
       'inv_no' => $request->inv_no,
       'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
       'Indate'=>$request->Indate,
       'supplierName' => $request->supplierName,
       'receiptNumber' => $request->receiptNumber,
       'truckNumber' => $request->truckNumber,
       'driverName' => $request->driverName,
       'remark' => $request->remark,
    ]);
}
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#other-creation-methods) for more info.

Comment: Bother, tested , it update the same data which i want to edit, but not create additional one which i entered

Answer (score 0):

I can see now what you need. If you put this `where(['id', $stock->id])` you will only find and update what already exists. Since your comparing with the values you searched doing `$stocks = Stock::where('inv_no', $inv_no)->get();`.

If you need to search where 'inv_no' is the value you inputed or create a new record, do:

```
Stock::updateOrCreate(['inv_no', $inv_no], [
   'pid' => $request->pid[$i],
   'qty' => $request->qty[$i],
   'inv_no' => $request->inv_no,
   'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
   'Indate'=>$request->Indate,
   'supplierName' => $request->supplierName,
   'receiptNumber' => $request->receiptNumber,
   'truckNumber' => $request->truckNumber,
   'driverName' => $request->driverName,
   'remark' => $request->remark,
]);
```

That way you are going to search any records with 'inv_no' equals the value you entered, update it or create a new value if it doesn't exists. Also, you can remove the lines `$stocks = Stock::where('inv_no', $inv_no)->get();` and `foreach ($stocks as $stock) {}`.

Comment: i get this error, `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `loadings` where (`0` = order_no and `1` = ONP1805200001) limit 1) `

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong. It should be 
`['inv_no' => $inv_no]` instead of `['inv_no', $inv_no]`

Comment: Let me know if it solved your issue. Notice it will only create a new record if there isn't any records, that is, if there's no Stock with 'inv_no' = $inv_no.

Comment: it update only that data are existing, but the issue here is to create the new `product_id` which i want to added on this `$inv_no` suppose i have `product_id` on this inv_no then i want to add the new product_id on the same inv_no

Answer (score 0):

`UpdateorCreate` is what you need but you must twist it so it works for your needs.

`UpdateOrCreate` can take 2 array parameters. The 1st array is basically your `where` clause telling the function to look for the specific parameters and if it finds them to update otherwise create a new record.

```
 Stock::updateOrCreate([
     'id' => $stock->id
     'pid' => $request->pid[$i],
     'inv_no' => $request->inv_no], 
     'qty' => $request->qty[$i],
   [
       'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
       'Indate'=>$request->Indate,
       'supplierName' => $request->supplierName,
       'receiptNumber' => $request->receiptNumber,
       'truckNumber' => $request->truckNumber,
       'driverName' => $request->driverName,
       'remark' => $request->remark,
    ]);
```

Not clear about your data but the above code will check in your database if there is a record with:

- id matching `$stock->id`
- pid matching `$request->pid[$i]`
- inv_no matching `$request->inv_no`

You can extend your where clause even further, you can even use only 1 array with all your data and tell the function to look for a record which has all the fields matching otherwise create a new record.

Comment: brother, your logic is good and tested its update the matching records only but not add the new  data of `request->pid and qty`,

Comment: Updated my answer. If it still not working that means that your counter is not working and ` $request->pid[$i]` and qty return always the same value. Try to debug it and echo your values.